# Emberjs - Get attribute of element clicked

Tags: ember.js

**Question:** Upon click, I see that evt.target.attributes stores all of the attributes in an array. Is there an easier way without having to iterate all of the attributes to get a certain attributes value? In this example I need the value of the 'note' attribute for the element clicked.

Template:

```
<a note="C" {{action "play" on="click"}}>></a>
```

Click handler(play):

```
var keys = Ember.View.create({
    templateName: 'keys',
    notes: this.get('allKeys'),
    play:function(evt){
        var attributes= evt.target.attributes;
        console.log(attributes);
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a controller isn't backing the view, one solution is to turn the event target into a jQuery object

```
play : function(event) {
    var note = $(event.target).attr("note");
    // More code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to pass the attribute value as parameter to the action.

```
<a note="C" onClick={{action "play" value="target.note"}}></a>
```

And you can access it like this:

```
...
actions: {
    play(note) {
        console.log(note);
    },
},
...
```